# Separating the POST requests of a Suitelet

Tags: javascript, post, netsuite, suitescript

My goal is to attach a custom Submit button to a Suitelet that sends a post request to an external server. The problem I am having is that when rendering the page the function `send()` within my custom button in `form.addButton('submit','Submit', send(form));` is running when the page is loaded. Because of this, no data is being sent to the `send()` function and therefore not being handled properly.

From what I understand, this problem has to do with the original POST request rendering the Suitelet and then interfering with the POST request I want to send.
What I need to do is separate or differentiate the POST request that renders the form from the one that sends the form. The ideal would be to have this done in a User Event Script but forms can only be used in Suitelets in SS1.0...

Is there any way this is possible? Should I use SuiteScript 2.0 to achieve this?
Below is how my code looks:

```
function main(request, response){
        var form = nlapiCreateForm('Submission Form');
        form.addField('one', 'text', 'Field 1');
        response.writePage(form);
        form.addButton('submit','Submit', send(form));      
}

function send(form){ process form data somewhere... }
```

Comment: Are you submitting the SuiteLet back to itself or calling some other endpoint? It would be helpful if you provided more context and the source, even distilled, of the send() method. Your comment to Adolfo makes me suspect you are missing a fundamental detail of SuiteLets.

Comment: I mentioned that I am sending the Suitelet form info to another server, as in not to itself. However, I have solved my problem by separating the send() function and storing it as an undeployed client script and then using the setScript function in the deployed mainFunction script. Now I am receiving a response from the server.

Comment: `response.getParamterValues(form)` threw me; that is what you would do if you were trying to access the submitted fields in the POST handler of the SuiteLet (i.e. server side). If you wanted to avoid the added complexity of the client script you could post the SuiteLet back to itself, log the data received (if you care) and then forward the request to the desired endpoint.

Comment: I posted the Suitelet back to itself. Works fine now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you are doing send(form) on the Suitelet you are actually running the function. The form.addButton method 3rd parameter accepts a string, so you want to do something like

`form.addButton('submit','Submit', "alert('Sending form')")`

You can add a whole stringified function if you want to build your own POST, although I think it would be easier to just include a form.addSubmitButton(label)  and that sends the form data to the same Suitelet and from there you can just send that data by POST using nlapiRequestURL

Comment: So then a simple `response.getParamterValues(form)` should give me the submitted form values. Is that correct?

Comment: My mistake, the way to get the value is by using `request.getParameter` not `response.getParameter`. I ended up just keeping it all in one Suitelet as you suggested.  Thanks!